# pad block corrupted during decryption(Android)

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm encrypting a file in java and send the encrypted file and private key to android device. But while decrypting the file in Android, it gives pad block corrupted error.
By the way, **same decryption code works on PC**

Here is the encryption:

```
public void encrypt(File inf, File outf, File publicKey, int userId, int resourceId) throws ArServerConnectionException {
    // ENCRYPTION BEGIN
    try {
        pkCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // create AES shared key cipher
    try {
        aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        makeKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            // File operation

            try {
        saveKey(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + userId
                + "/keyfile"), publicKey);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // File operation

    try {
        encryptFiles(inf, outf);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // /ENCRYPTION END
}

    public void saveKey(File out, File publicKeyFile) throws IOException,
        GeneralSecurityException {
    // read public key to be used to encrypt the AES key
    byte[] encodedKey = new byte[(int) publicKeyFile.length()];
    new FileInputStream(publicKeyFile).read(encodedKey);

    // create public key
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pk = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

    // write AES key
    pkCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
    CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(out), pkCipher);
    os.write(aesKey);
    os.close();
}
    public void makeKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    kgen.init(AES_Key_Size);
    SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
    aesKey = key.getEncoded();
    aeskeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
}
```

Here is the decryption part:

```
public class FileDecrypt {
    public static final int AES_Key_Size = 256;

    Cipher pkCipher, aesCipher;
    byte[] aesKey;
    SecretKeySpec aeskeySpec;
    private String pubKeyPath=null;
    private String prvKeyPath=null;
    private String keyFilePath=null;
    private String encFilePath=null;
    private String unencFilePath=null;


    public String getEncFilePath() {
        return encFilePath;
    }

    public void setEncFilePath(String encFilePath) {
        this.encFilePath = encFilePath;
    }

    public String getUnencFilePath() {
        return unencFilePath;
    }

    public void setUnencFilePath(String unencFilePath) {
        this.unencFilePath = unencFilePath;
    }

    public String getPubKeyPath() {
        return pubKeyPath;
    }

    public void setPubKeyPath(String pubKeyPath) {
        this.pubKeyPath = pubKeyPath;
    }

    public String getPrvKeyPath() {
        return prvKeyPath;
    }

    public void setPrvKeyPath(String prvKeyPath) {
        this.prvKeyPath = prvKeyPath;
    }

    public String getKeyFilePath() {
        return keyFilePath;
    }

    public void setKeyFilePath(String keyFilePath) {
        this.keyFilePath = keyFilePath;
    }
    public void decrypt() {
        Log.i("DECRYPT","**************************************************DECRYPT&*******************");
        Log.i("encFilePath",encFilePath);
        Log.i("pubKeyPath",pubKeyPath);
        Log.i("prvKeyPath",prvKeyPath);
        Log.i("keyFilePath",keyFilePath);
        Log.i("unencFilePath",unencFilePath);
        Log.i("DECRYPT","********************************************DECRYPT&*******************");
        try {
            pkCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //DECRYPTION BEGIN

        File pkf=new File(pubKeyPath);
        byte[] encodedKey = new byte[(int) pkf.length()];
        try {
            new FileInputStream(pkf).read(encodedKey);
            // create public key
            X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PublicKey pk = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

            // write AES key
            pkCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            loadKey(new File(keyFilePath), new File(prvKeyPath));
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            decrypt(new File(encFilePath), new File(unencFilePath));
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //DECRYPTION END
    }

    /**
     * Decrypts an AES key from a file using an RSA private key
     */
    public void loadKey(File in, File privateKeyFile)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        // read private key to be used to decrypt the AES key
        byte[] encodedKey = new byte[(int) privateKeyFile.length()];
        new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile).read(encodedKey);

        // create private key
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey pk = kf.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

        // read AES key
        pkCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pk);
        aesKey = new byte[AES_Key_Size / 8];
        CipherInputStream is = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(in),
                pkCipher);
        is.read(aesKey);
        aeskeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
    }

    /**
     * Decrypts and then copies the contents of a given file.
     */
    public void decrypt(File in, File out) throws IOException
         {
        try {
            aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            Log.i("EXCEPTION","INVALID KEY EXCEPTION");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        CipherInputStream is = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(in),
                aesCipher);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);

        copy(is, os);

        is.close();
        os.close();
    }

    /**
     * Copies a stream.
     */
    private void copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        int i;
        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        while ((i = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were also facing the same issue, It was solved only on doing the encrypting part too on android side(Using android SDK) and then decrypting it on device. No other correct reasons were found for the issue..

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is the code you are using to send the file to the device is incorrect. Perhaps it is truncating, padding or otherwise corrupting the data so it doesn't decrypt properly. Try testing with a static file and see if you can isolate the issue.

Comment: I'm getting the file from device and testing it in my PC and it is decrypted properly. Therefore it made me think there is no problem in transfering the file

Answer (score 0):

The PC where you are encrypting the file is using a different security provider (mostly SunJCE) and the android uses security provider "BC" (Bouncy Castle prior to 4.2, AndroidOpenssl after 4.2) to decrypt the file. Hence the decryption is not successful at android device. Please use bouncy castle jar corresponding to your PC type from this location [Bouncy castle jar download](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).

Encrypt using the provider "BC" in java code in PC.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES", "BC");
```

Decyption will work fine at android side :)